# Autofac - Is it possible to intercept all registrations with an interceptor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, aop

I have read a past [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782086/autofac-global-interface-interceptor-with-autofac-extras-dynamicproxy2) which talked about this topic. However, it no longer works. May I know in 2022, is there a way to intercept all registration? e.g. use for AOP logging